# How to insert big GeoJson and not get kill process?

Tags: postgis, geojson

I have been trying to insert a `geojson` into `postgis`.

Both of my `geojson` exceed 300 MB.

When I tried

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" name.shp "name.geojson"
```

or

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=name user=user" name.geojson -nln newtable
```

both processes just show "Killed", with no describing error, not anything more.

How should I check why it is killed? How to insert my big `geojsons` into `postgis`?

Comment: You could try using the Postgres copy command to upload your json into a table as text, then use Postgis commands to parse the geojson.

Comment: How big is your geojson file? Could a solution similar to that one help? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795511/how-to-convert-featurecollection-to-geometrycollection-or-multipolygon/57797929#57797929)