# How to convert FeatureCollection to GeometryCollection or MultiPolygon?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geojson

I have many polygons that need to be drawn manually and then get geo-coordinates.
I need to get the coordinates of the drawn polygons in GeoJSON format.

In this format:

```
"{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[37.4653933,55.3959159]...}"
"{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[37.475738525390625,55.41420507450017]...}"
```

Or in this:

```
"{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-98.0419921875,39.027718840211605]...}]}"
```

I draw polygons at http://geojson.io/.
But from this site I can only get data in the format with the FeatureCollection type.
I found another site - https://rodic.fr/blog/online-conversion-between-geometric-formats/, on which I can convert to GeoJSON format, but this site can only convert type GeometryCollection.

I cannot find how to convert FeatureCollection to GeometryCollection or MultiPolygon or to Polygon.

How to solve?
Many thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the coordinates in the geojson format, you can use the following snippet:

```
WITH geojson_featurecollection AS (
    SELECT ''::json AS fc
)
SELECT (json_array_elements(fc->'features'))->>'geometry'
FROM geojson_featurecollection;
```

in which you paste your entire FeatureCollection definition (coming from the http://geojson.io website after your edits) inside of the quotes

Comment: Yes! Its work perfectly!!) Big thx to you!) I have found another code to convert in multipolygon. I will test both codes. Ones more thx to you!) `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Collect(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feat->>'geometry')))
FROM (
  SELECT json_array_elements('PUT_HERE'::json->'features') AS feat
) AS f;` [From here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/storing-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgresql-with-postgis)